# ¿Cómo crear un footer que se adapte en la parte inferior?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

La mayor parte de la mayoría de soluciones se basa en crear un footer fijó `position: fixed`.

Otras alternativas que se dan es una posición absoluta.

**Ejemplo**

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

> Pero un footer flotante no es de agradó, no es una solución peormente cuando tenemos un menú flotante y un footer con un `height` con un extremó demasiado alto.

Pero cuál es la idea de tener un footer que permanezca en la parte inferior.

- Que permanezca solo en la parte inferior cuando el área de los contenidos o la información no agrupa en cantidad.

**Ejemplo** (área con contenido corto).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una solución para obtener un footer de esta mamera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para mostrar un footer solo cuando el área del contenido tiene muy poca información.

Una solución sería con jQuery detectar la altura y aplicar una class para adaptar firmemente el footer en la parte inferior.

Cómo se plantaría un solución con **jQuery** (*para los amantes de programación jquery*).

O que otras alternativas se puede aplicar con css sin que el footer sea flotante?

Comment: ¿Quieres que el footer esté siempre visible?¿o solo que se ajuste a la parte inferior de la página (que puede o no ser la parte inferior de la ventana)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro solo que se ajuste en la parte inferior de la página (que permanezca siempre abajo), pero está alternativa sólo cuando el contenido del área es corta. Porque cuándo existe un contenido extenso no existe problemas con el footer. ( *Aunque algunos ejemplos no estarían mal, para aclarar dudas para otros usuarios* ). Ahora sobre  un footer siempre visible con un menú de navegación flotante quedaría muy mal. Saludos :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para esto no necesitas ni JavaScript/jQuery ni HTML5/CSS3, hay una solución con CSS que funciona hasta con versiones antiguas de navegadores. La idea es la siguiente:

- Haz que el documento ocupe todo el alto de la página (pon `height:100%` para el `html` y `body`.
- Encapsula todo el contenido de tu página en un contenedor que también ocupe el 100% del alto y tenga posición relativa.
- El contenido de tu página tendrá un `padding` abajo igual o mayor que el alto del pie de página
- El pie de página estará posicionado de manera absoluta abajo del contenido que encapsula todo.

El código se vería así:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}

#pagina {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#contenido {
  padding-bottom:50px; /* este valor debe ser igual o mayor al alto del pie */
}

#pie {
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagina">
  <div id="cabecera">LOGO</div>
  <div id="contenido"></div>
  <div id="pie">2016 &copy; Nombre Empresa</div>
</div>
```

---

Como quieres una alternativa con JavaScript/jQuery, aquí te pongo una; aunque te comento que puede haber muchas posibilidades y, como mencionaba en un comentario, realmente no hace falta con el CSS descrito arriba.

La idea sería hacer algo como esto:

- Poner los diferentes elementos en la página, sin importar alturas ni nada
- Hacer que el footer tenga posición absoluta pero no especificar cuál.
- Crear una función que:

  - Calcule el alto del documento
  - Calcule el alto de la ventana
  - Calcule el alto del pie/footer
  - Si el alto del documento + el alto del footer es menor que el alto de la ventana, entonces hacer que el footer se pegue abajo
  - Si no, dejar el footer donde está
- Crear un controlador para que se llame a la función creada en el paso anterior al cargar la página y al redimensionar la ventana.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podría hacerse:

```js
function ajustarPie() {
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var docH = $("body").height();
  var pieH = $("footer").height();
  
  if (docH + pieH < winH) {
    $("footer").attr("class", "bottom");
    } else {
      $("footer").attr("class", "");
      }
  }

$(document).ready(ajustarPie);
$(window).on("resize", ajustarPie);
```

```css
footer {
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}

footer.bottom {
  bottom:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>LOGO</header>
<main>
  <p>Párrafo 1</p>
  <p>Párrafo 2</p>
  <p>Párrafo 3</p>
  <p>Párrafo 4</p>
  <p>Párrafo 5</p>
</main>
<footer>
  2016 &copy; Nombre empresa
</footer>
```

Comment: Solo una duda no te molestes sí... Si en el caso que yo solo quisiera solucionar el problema solo cuando el contenido es como de la primera imagen con jQuery. ¿Como lo realizaría? Un dato adicional en tu pregunta si, tu respuesta es perfecta solo un dato como adicional :)

Comment: Con ese CSS no necesitarías hacer nada de JS.  Si cambiaras el CSS Podrías crear un controlador del evento resize para la ventana que calculase la nueva posición

Comment: Ahora no estoy en el ordenador. Pero cuando esté en uno te pongo un ejemplo

Comment: @J.Doe Añadí una alternativa con JavaScript/jQuery. Saludos

Comment: Sos grande amigo, disculpa la molestia pero muchos quizás tendrán alguna duda así cómo la mía y de seguro sera de mucha referencia y de ayuda para futuros lectores. Buen día :)

Answer (score 3):

> solo que se ajuste en la parte inferior de la página (que permanezca siempre abajo), pero está alternativa sólo cuando el contenido del área es corta. Porque cuándo existe un contenido extenso no existe problemas con el footer

Puedes hacerlo mediante flexbox:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}
.content p {
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}
.content p:first-letter {
  font-size: 20pt;
}
footer {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: .5rem .8rem;
}
footer p {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,9);
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed provident explicabo corporis ad consequatur possimus at recusandae, minus nostrum a laudantium doloremque voluptates, pariatur officiis deleniti molestiae. Quas, quae, minima!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam consectetur consequatur, natus unde, deserunt sit voluptate a nesciunt vero in inventore quidem! Voluptate, saepe, veritatis laborum mollitia assumenda placeat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, rem, aut. Mollitia quasi, rem vero delectus iusto optio dolorum alias assumenda commodi quod, cum incidunt dolore pariatur ad minus voluptatem.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora laudantium accusamus unde provident possimus rem nemo officiis, quam perferendis, optio repudiandae nulla rerum doloremque culpa, dignissimos veniam aliquid aliquam ratione?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos quos hic rerum, ipsum similique nostrum quis cum repellat eum veritatis magnam vero tempore sequi facere alias, laudantium esse. Nihil, impedit.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, at in! Velit placeat incidunt quidem perspiciatis officiis consequuntur! Tempora nihil nam nemo harum quia adipisci aut, omnis, magni totam quae!
    </p>
    
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
  </footer>
```

Prueba sacando dos `p` para que veas el comportamiento.

Comment: Debiste decir únicamente jQuery :P. Has puesto: *O que otras alternativas se puede aplicar con css sin que el footer sea flotante?*. De todos modos, ¿por qué quieres hacerlo con jQuery si puedes hacerlo con CSS? ¿Necesitas que soporte navegadores viejos? En ese caso, si se cumple la condición de **si el tamaño del contenido + el tamaño del footer es < al viewport height**, entonces, ponlo `fixed` con `bottom: 0`.

Comment: No te molestes sí... Si en el caso que yo solo quisiera solucionar el problema solo cuando el contenido es como de la primera imagen con jQuery. ¿Como lo realizaría? Un dato adicional en tu pregunta si, sólo es un dato como adicional (*dos ejemplo en uno no estaría mal*) además sería muy útil como referencia para futuros lectores que tengan la misma duda? :)

Comment: Vale, en un momento trataré de poner un demo con jQuery (ahora estoy en móvil). PD: No me molesto xD